# Fixed points of the action of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, smooth-manifolds

Hello!

If a compact Lie group $K$ acts smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$, then the set $M^K$ of fixed points under this action is a smooth submanifold of $M$. This is proved for example in Duistermaat's book on Lie groups, using the Bochner Linearization Theorem.

I am interested in knowing if some variant of this statement is also true in algebraic geometry. In other words: can one describe a class of algebraic groups where the fixed points for an arbitrary action on a smooth variety is again smooth?

Thank you!

Hanno

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linearly reductive groups, that is, linear algebraic groups, say over a field, in which the functor of invariants from finite dimensional representations to vector spaces is exact. I am not sure this is in the literature in this generality, but it is not so hard to prove with a formal scheme argument.

Also, I would conjecture that this is optimal, that is, given a non linearly reductive algebraic group, one can find a smooth variety on which this acts, such that the fixed point locus is not smooth.

Comment: A reference is Birger Iversen, A fixed point formula for action of tori on algebraic varieties, Invent. Math., 1972.

Comment: @DanPetersen's reference, clickably:  [Iversen - A fixed point formula for action of tori on algebraic varieties](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01425495) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=299608)).  Despite the title, some of the results handle arbitrary linearly reductive groups.  (Note that linearly reductive = reductive in characteristic 0.)

Answer (score 5):

Angelo's [conjectural statement](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60664) is proven in Fogarty, J.; Norman, P. "[A fixed-point characterization of linearly reductive groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780120805501500159)." [MR0485896](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=485896)

(not enough reputation to post this as comment, sorry)

Comment: These sorts of answers that usefully supplement another answer (even if not directly addressing the OP's question) have typically been accepted by the community as worth keeping around, and so I think we can let it stand, if only for the sake of getting the poster to the 50-point threshold (so that next time he/she can comment instead).